# Ubuntu 20.04.2 Ethernet Disconnects on System Resume

Tags: networking, network-manager

On system resume from suspend, ethernet remains briefly connected and connections can be made. After about 5-10s, the device disconnects and automatically reconnects. Since the connection is already preserved established on resume, it seems unusual that network manager proceeds to disconnect and reconnect. I have attempted to search for similar errors, however the experience of most users appears to be one of the following:

- Interface **never** comes back up after resume
- Wifi not available after resume
- Connection intermittently dropping out
- Various other power saving related issues

I've attempted to disable power saving on the interface by setting `/sys/class/net/enp6s0/power/control` to `on`.

Ethernet devices are:

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

The intel one is in use.

Note in the log below that network manager puts the device into unmanaged at `11:27:16`, and according to `/var/log/syslog`, the system came out of resume at `11:27:00`

```
May 09 22:51:12 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620640272.8868] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
May 09 22:51:12 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620640272.8868] device (enp5s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 09 22:51:12 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620640272.9488] device (<bluetooth-redacted>): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 09 22:51:12 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620640272.9491] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP

|

May 10 11:27:03 <hostname-redacted> kernel: [154647.921847] igb 0000:06:00.0 enp6s0: igb: enp6s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX

|

May 10 11:27:16 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678436.9239] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
May 10 11:27:16 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678436.9240] device (enp6s0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 10 11:27:16 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678436.9489] dhcp4 (enp6s0): canceled DHCP transaction
May 10 11:27:16 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678436.9489] dhcp4 (enp6s0): state changed bound -> done
May 10 11:27:16 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678436.9492] dhcp6 (enp6s0): canceled DHCP transaction
May 10 11:27:16 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678436.9492] dhcp6 (enp6s0): state changed bound -> done
May 10 11:27:16 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678436.9537] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
May 10 11:27:16 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678436.9832] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 10 11:27:16 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678436.9842] device (enp5s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 10 11:27:17 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678437.2059] device (enp6s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 10 11:27:17 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678437.2306] device (<bluetooth-redacted>): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 10 11:27:17 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678437.2317] device (<bluetooth-redacted>): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 10 11:27:20 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678440.8616] device (enp6s0): carrier: link connected
May 10 11:27:20 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678440.8618] device (enp6s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 10 11:27:20 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678440.8628] policy: auto-activating connection 'Ethernet' (ec1845cf-b56b-413b-865e-66ae2ed76c0d)
May 10 11:27:20 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678440.8632] device (enp6s0): Activation: starting connection 'Ethernet' (ec1845cf-b56b-413b-865e-66ae2ed76c0d)
May 10 11:27:20 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678440.8632] device (enp6s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 10 11:27:20 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678440.8635] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
May 10 11:27:20 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678440.9094] device (enp6s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 10 11:27:20 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678440.9105] device (enp6s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 10 11:27:20 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678440.9108] dhcp4 (enp6s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 10 11:27:24 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678444.6296] device (enp6s0): carrier: link connected
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.1534] dhcp6 (enp6s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.1638] dhcp6 (enp6s0): option dhcp6_name_servers   => '<redacted>'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.1638] dhcp6 (enp6s0): state changed unknown -> bound
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6313] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option dhcp_lease_time      => '604800'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6313] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option domain_name          => '<redacted>'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6313] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option domain_name_servers  => '<redacted>'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6313] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option expiry               => '1621283245'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6313] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option host_name            => '<hostname-redacted>'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6313] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option ip_address           => '10.0.0.50'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option next_server          => '10.0.0.1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_domain_name => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_domain_search => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_host_name  => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_root_path  => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_routers    => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6314] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_static_routes => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6315] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6315] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_time_offset => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6315] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option requested_wpad       => '1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6315] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option routers              => '10.0.0.1'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6315] dhcp4 (enp6s0): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6315] dhcp4 (enp6s0): state changed unknown -> bound
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6331] device (enp6s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6352] device (enp6s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6355] device (enp6s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6360] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6371] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6372] policy: set 'Ethernet' (enp6s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6374] policy: set 'Ethernet' (enp6s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6379] device (enp6s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
May 10 11:27:25 <hostname-redacted> NetworkManager[1280]: <info>  [1620678445.6385] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
```

**Edit** I've isolated this issue to NetworkManager, disabling it and using networkd resolves the problem. However, I'd still prefer a solution which uses NetworkManager.